# Increment a value

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a question, how to make that the value increments like b=0 then next b=1 then b=3

my code is printing 111 but the output that I want is 123 I've also tried b=b+1; but also the printed output is 111

```
for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
    int b=0;
    b++;
    b=b+b++;
    System.out.print(b);
}
```

Comment: Sit down with a piece of paper and columns marked `x` and `b`, and by hand go through the program.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `b` before the loop. Increment in the loop. Like,

```
int b = 1;
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    System.out.print(b++);
}
```

**or**

```
int b = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    System.out.print(++b);
}
```

Both output "123". Your current code declares **and** initializes `b` as the first statement in the loop body and is equivalent to `int b = 1;` - and thus you print `1` three times. It is possible to limit `b`'s lifetime to the loop, but you would declare it at the same scope as `x`. Like,

```
for (int x = 0, b = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    System.out.print(++b);
}
```

Or eliminate `b` altogether and use `x`. Like,

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir haha im too idiot in programming im only freshmen so thats why hihi

Comment: This is  a pure solution. Will the answer be better with pointing to read about scope and lifetime of variables in java first? Then suggest to find the error and the solution at the end.

Comment: @uli This is three lines of code. In fact, there was so little meat, I wrote it twice.

Comment: I understand, but this example shows that OP has gaps in scope and lifetime of variables. And there could be more complicated cases in future. With one sentence you could possibly eliminate several similar future questions. Will it be better?!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting `b = 0` in every iteration.

Hence, in all the 3 iterations you are getting the same value of the variable b.

Take it outside the loop to get the desired result.

Example:

```
int b=1; // initialize to 1
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   System.out.print(b); // print the value.
   b = b + 1; // increment the value by 1
}
```

This code is same as:

```
int b=1; 
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   System.out.print(b++); 
}
```